# What prophets came before Muhammad PBUH?

Tags: prophets

I am interested in researching the words of the other prophets as well as Muhammad PBUH, but I am unclear on who came before. I would like to know where people lost, confused, or abandoned their messages. Wikipedia has [an entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_in_Islam), but I'd prefer Qur'anic verses or hadiths, of course.

Specifically, I would like to know

- How many prophets came before Muhammad PBUH?
- Who were they?
- Where can I find out about them? (Scholarly resources preferred)

Comment: Maybe a better formulation of this question and a more likely answerable one is which prophets who came before Muhammad have been quoted in the Qur'an and sunnah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find an authentic record for stories of the prophet in the medieval book [Stories of Prophets by the famous scholar Ibn Kathir](http://www.kalamullah.com/Books/Stories%20Of%20The%20Prophets%20By%20Ibn%20Kathir.pdf).

Here are the prophets mentioned in the table of contents:

> 1. Prophet Adam
> 2. Prophet Idris (Enoch)
> 3. Prophet Nuh (Noah)
> 4. Prophet Hud
> 5. Prophet Salih
> 6. Prophet Ibrahim (Abraham)
> 7. Prophet Isma'il (Ishmael)
> 8. Prophet Ishaq (Isaac)
> 9. Prophet Yaqub (Jacob)
> 10. Prophet Lot (Lot)
> 11. Prophet Shuaib
> 12. Prophet Yusuf (Joseph)
> 13. Prophet Ayoub (Job)
> 14. Prophet Dhul-Kifl
> 15. Prophet Yunus (Jonah)
> 16. Prophet Musa (Moses) & Harun (Aaron)
> 17. Prophet Hizqeel (Ezekiel)
> 18. Prophet Elyas (Elisha)
> 19. Prophet Shammil (Samuel)
> 20. Prophet Dawud (David)
> 21. Prophet Sulaiman (Soloman)
> 22. Prophet Shia (Isaiah)
> 23. Prophet Aramaya (Jeremiah)
> 24. Prophet Daniel
> 25. Prophet Uzair (Ezra)
> 26. Prophet Zakariyah (Zechariah)
> 27. Prophet Yahya (John)
> 28. Prophet Isa (Jesus)
> 29. Prophet Muhammad PBUH

Answer (score 0):

According to Islam and Quran, there are 1 Lac 24 thousand prophets sent to the world to teach the people the message of Allah. But among them, there are several whose name has been mentioned in Quran.

They were the prophets of Allah. You can read there name, and other information here: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_in_Islam)

What else you want to read about them? Please refer the link I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are 124.000 nabi and 315 rasool that Allah send to guide human kind to worship Allah Ta'ala (see Imam Ahmad Hadits book).  But in Islam we just have to have faith in 25 prophets that are mentioned in the Qur'an.  These 25 prophets comprise of 20 nabi and 5 rasool.

Why only 25? because we can use their life story as guide in our life time.

Is there other prophet's life story cannot we use as guide? Only Allah Ta'ala know the best.

According to the list of 25 prophets; the prophets before rasool Muhammad shalallahu 'alaihi wa sallam include rasool Isa 'alaihis salaam.
But again, we just know the 25 prophet name in the Qur'an, so only Allah Ta'ala know if there any prophet before prophet Muhammad Shalallahu 'alaihi wa sallam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 25 prophets are mentioned in the Qur'an but we should have faith in all the prophets meaning we should believed that,there are other prophets.

Answer (score 0):

In the message of the Qur'an, the names of the prophets mentioned in the Qur'an are as follows:

1. Hazrat Adam. 2. Hazrat Idris. 3. Hazrat Noah. 4. Hazrat Hood. 5. Hazrat Saleh. 6. Hazrat Ibrahim. 7. Hazrat Ishaq. 8. Hazrat Ismail. 9 .Hazrat Lot. 10 .Hazrat Ya'qub. 11. Hazrat Yusuf. 12 .Hazrat Ayub. 13 .Hazrat Shoaib. 14 .Hazrat Musa. 15 .Hazrat Haroon. 16 .حضرت اشموعيل. 17 .Hazrat Elias. 18 .حضرت اليسع. 19 .حضرت ذوالكفل. 20 .Hazrat Davood. 21 .Hazrat Suleiman. 22. Hazrat Yunus. 23 .Hazrat Zakaria. 24 .حضرت يحيى. 25 .Hazrat Jesus. 26 .Hazrat Azir. 27 .Hazrat Muhammad, the Holy Prophet of Islam.

Ref: https://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/22915

Answer (score -1):

Prophet Adam
Prophet Shees
Prophet Idris (Enoch)
Prophet Nuh (Noah)
Prophet Salih
Prophet Ibrahim (Abraham) & hazrat Loot
Prophet Isma'il (Ishmael)
Prophet Ishaq (Isaac)
Prophet Yaqub (Jacob)
Prophet Yusuf (Joseph
Prophet Shoaib
Prophet Ayoub (Job)
 14 . Prophet Dhul-Kifl
Prophet Yunus (Jonah)
Prophet Musa (Moses) & Harun (Aaron)
Prophet Hizqeel (Ezekiel)
Prophet Elyas (Elisha) & Hazrat Yassa
Prophet Shammil (Samuel)
Prophet Dawud (David)
Prophet Sulaiman (Soloman)
Prophet Shia (Isaiah)
Prophet Aramaya (Jeremiah)
Prophet Daniel
Prophet Uzair (Ezra)
Prophet Zakariyah (Zechariah)
Prophet Yahya (John)
Prophet Isa (Jesus)
Prophet Muhammad PBUH

Answer (score -2):

Read this book very recommended, what is before Muhammad the 24 prophets stories in Islam:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08ZW85PPL/ref=nodl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08ZW85PPL)_